# Count the number of observations

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with the following variables serial (identification number), Day (week days from Mon.- Sun) that is usex to record the starting day of an observation and 7 variables day1 to day7 each representing a day of the week. Day1 is Mon and Day7 is Sun.

I would like to identify the number of days of any observation. The starting day is recorded in Day. For example in the case of id 12 the number of days is 7. In the case of id 9 is 4.

One way  to do this is using colSum() function. Is a better/faster way?

Input:

```
  serial  day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6 day7 Day
    12    2    1    2    1    1    3    1   Monday
   123    0    3    0    3    3    0    3   Tuesday
    10    0    3    3    3    3    3    3   Thursday
```

Output:

```
serial  Length
    12      7       
    123     4       
    10      6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical `matrix` of 'day' column i.e. by checking whether the values are greater than 0

```
cbind(df1['serial'], Length = rowSums(df1[startsWith(names(df1), 'day')] > 0))
#    serial Length
#1     12      7
#2    123      4
#3     10      6
```

---

Or another option is `Reduce` with `lapply`

```
cbind(df1['serial'], Length = Reduce(`+`, 
           lapply(df1[startsWith(names(df1), 'day')], `>`, 0)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(serial = c(12L, 123L, 10L), day1 = c(2L, 0L, 0L
), day2 = c(1L, 3L, 3L), day3 = c(2L, 0L, 3L), day4 = c(1L, 3L, 
3L), day5 = c(1L, 3L, 3L), day6 = c(3L, 0L, 3L), day7 = c(1L, 
3L, 3L), Day = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```